# deploying a new version of a GWT project to GAE doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a problem deploying to GAE. I have deployed new versions many times, but now it creates the new staging directory properly, but it uploads 0 files to the server. It is like it doesn't notice the code changes. And when I execute it in the server it doesn't make anything, not even activate an instance.

Thanks in advance.

Configuration:
GWT 2.4
GAE 1.5.4

Comment: Are you sure you did make any changes? App Engine only uploads modified files. And what do you mean by "when I execute it in the server it doesn't make anything, not even activate an instance"?

Comment: At the end I upgraded to another SDK and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to rollback a failed update. In the eclipse plugin directory will a folder named appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5. Inside the bin subfolder is a program called appcfg.cmd (I think, there may be a different extension). From the command line run:

appcfg.cmd rollback C:/path/to/war_directory

Comment: If you have a free app slot left, how about trying to upload it to a different instance and see if it works there? At least narrow down the problem.